How to modify folder add commit after git push?
I couldn't add a folder remote by type "foldername/" online - the "commit" was blocked, then I mkdir locate and git add foldername - git commit - git puah, everything was OK, but I could find my folder added remote, while the commit info was shown, I thought maybe I should have typed "git add foldername/" (attached slash in the end), and this time after git commit, it was prompted:
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

I still couldn't find the folder added remote, how to fix this?

You can't check a directory into git.  You can't edit directories, so there's nothing to check in. You have to check in files in the directory .

Thanks, I added a file directly after I created the directory, then it was OK.

Git is designed to manage edited files.   You can't edit directories, so there's nothing to check in.  You have to check in files in the directory.
Presumably if you want to keep a directory, you're going to put something into it you will check in.  But if you really do just want an empty directory, you can create an empty file, like touch .keep and check that in.
